# Trying to use Selenium to find a specific entry in a list when what you type highlights that word

Tags: selenium

DOM:

```
<span class="item">Does not <span class="highlight">match</span>.</span>
<span class="item">Also not <span class="highlight">match</span>ing.</span>
<span class="item"><span class="highlight">match</span></span>
```

Issue:
I've got a list of items.  When I type into a text box, it eliminates items that do not match, and highlights the ones that do inside a /span.  The issue is that if I type something that matches multiple things, I want to select the EXACT String, and not the ones that partially match (see above DOM example...  the ideal match would be the 3rd one).

So, is my only hope here to go one by one until I find my perfect match, or is there something else that I've been missing?

Comment: If you're looking for exact text, you can use an `XPath` as your selector to get it. `//span[@class='item'][text()='exact entire string']`. Would that satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Sorry, took my brain a minute to figure out the exact requirement here, I think you want to check that there isn't any text in the outer span like this - `//span[@class='item'][not(text())]/span[@class='highlight'][text()='match']`. I think this is what you want so I'll post as an answer. I can make it more customized if you can post some code of how you are trying to get this element.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a `span` that has no text, with an inner `span` that has some highlighted text. Here is an `XPath` selector for that:

```
//span[@class='item'][not(text())]/span[@class='highlight'][‌​text()='match']
```

Comment: Note that this will match the inner `span`, if you want the outer `span` you'll have to use a forward axis or traverse back up the tree. Let me know if you have questions with this.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.  Never knew there was such a thing as not(text()).

Comment: Glad to hear it! Feel free to accept the answer and upvote if you feel so inclined :)